# Is there a way to link 2 arrays without having a default key?

Tags: arrays, awk, associative

This is what is in the file .txt where i'm trying my script:

```
-2 -2 -4 -2 50
-2 -4 -1 -7 20
-5 -6 -1 -8 50
23 -2 -5 -8 -2
5 -2 -1 -1 -5
-8 -3 -5 -6 1
-5 23 -21 -5 -6
-2 -6 -9 34 -21
-2 -3 -4 -5 -6
-1 -3 -5 -8 9
10 -6 -7 -9 2
-10 -45 -21 -5 -10
```

The correct result should be:

```
Jan -10
Feb -14
mar -20
etc

#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
print "Month ------------- Negative budget"
}

{
sum=0
for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
    if($i<0){
        sum = sum + $i
    }
}

n=split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", months)
}

{
SM[key]=sum
}

{
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    print months[i], SM[key]

}
```

```
Month ------------- Negative budget
Jan -10
Feb -10
Mar -10
Apr -10
May -10
Jun -10
Jul -10
Aug -10
Sep -10
Oct -10
Nov -10
Dec -10
Jan -14
Feb -14
Mar -14
Apr -14
May -14
Jun -14
Jul -14
Aug -14
Sep -14
Oct -14
Nov -14
Dec -14
Jan -20
Feb -20
Mar -20
Apr -20
May -20
Jun -20
Jul -20
Aug -20
Sep -20
Oct -20
Nov -20
Dec -20
Jan -17
Feb -17
Mar -17
Apr -17
May -17
Jun -17
Jul -17
Aug -17
Sep -17
Oct -17
Nov -17
Dec -17
Jan -9
Feb -9
Mar -9
Apr -9
May -9
Jun -9
Jul -9
Aug -9
Sep -9
Oct -9
Nov -9
Dec -9
Jan -22
Feb -22
Mar -22
Apr -22
May -22
Jun -22
Jul -22
Aug -22
Sep -22
Oct -22
Nov -22
Dec -22
Jan -37
Feb -37
Mar -37
Apr -37
May -37
Jun -37
Jul -37
Aug -37
Sep -37
Oct -37
Nov -37
Dec -37
Jan -38
Feb -38
Mar -38
Apr -38
May -38
Jun -38
Jul -38
Aug -38
Sep -38
Oct -38
Nov -38
Dec -38
Jan -20
Feb -20
Mar -20
Apr -20
May -20
Jun -20
Jul -20
Aug -20
Sep -20
Oct -20
Nov -20
Dec -20
Jan -17
Feb -17
Mar -17
Apr -17
May -17
Jun -17
Jul -17
Aug -17
Sep -17
Oct -17
Nov -17
Dec -17
Jan -22
Feb -22
Mar -22
Apr -22
May -22
Jun -22
Jul -22
Aug -22
Sep -22
Oct -22
Nov -22
Dec -22
Jan -91
Feb -91
Mar -91
Apr -91
May -91
Jun -91
Jul -91
Aug -91
Sep -91
Oct -91
Nov -91
Dec -91
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate through the columns in your line to get the sum. This is good. But then you iterate again through the columns to print your months and total. You only want one line printed for each line of input, so printing inside an iteration of columns of your line is obviously going to produce too much output.

Your months don't fit to your columns, but they do fit to your lines/records, so use the `NR` (row number) to work with that `months` array and print:

```
BEGIN {
print "Month ------------- Negative budget"
n=split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", months)
}

{
    sum=0
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        if($i<0){
            sum = sum + $i
        }
    }

    print months[NR], sum
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another version

```
echo "-2 -2 -4 -2 50
-2 -4 -1 -7 20
-5 -6 -1 -8 50
23 -2 -5 -8 -2
5 -2 -1 -1 -5
-8 -3 -5 -6 1
-5 23 -21 -5 -6
-2 -6 -9 34 -21
-2 -3 -4 -5 -6
-1 -3 -5 -8 9
10 -6 -7 -9 2
-10 -45 -21 -5 -10" | awk -F' ' '{sum=0;for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i<0) sum+=$i; SM[NR] = sum;} END{n=split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", months); print "Month ------------- Negative budget"; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print months[i]"\t\t\t "SM[i]}'
```

Cheers